# Script to import information from another source into an areas of a config file?

Tags: linux

I have a configuration file (.conf) that looks like this example:

`[[inputs.snmp]]
name = "snmp.dsm"
agents = ["192.168.1.1:161" , "192.168.1.2:161" , "192.168.1.3:161" , "192.168.1.4:161"]

```
timeout = "3s"
retries = 5

[[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "sysName"
    oid = "RFC1213-MIB::sysName.0"
    is_tag = true

[[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "sysUpTime"
    oid = "RFC1213-MIB::sysUpTime.0"`
```

The line called 'agents' on my real config contains many more IP's that change, so I need to keep editing this list which polls these IPs.  We have a database that spits out the IPs to a csv each day in the format of:

`192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4` etc

Is there a scripting language I could look into that could look at this csv and replace what is in the .conf file on lines 3 and set as a cron job?  I'm not that good at programming but prepared to look into it, I'm just not sure which language or terminology to start looking into that's all.  It's a shame they don't use DNS on this, but that's another story.

Thanks

Nothing yet, I need guidance.